# Go1.18: Debugging programs compiled with go version go1.18 darwin/amd64 is not supported. Use go sdk for darwin/arm64

Tags: go

after i upgrade my go version up to 1.18 from 1.17,
when i using goland to debug , the goland give me a feedback that:
Debugging programs compiled with go version go1.18 darwin/amd64 is not supported. Use go sdk for darwin/arm64.

is anybody have the same question? please give me some tips to fix it, Thanks ~~

Comment: It looks like you’re on arm64, but installed amd64

Answer (score 0):

Need to revert to golang 1.17. I've run into several issues with 1.18 darwin/arm64 and they don't seem to be fixing them very fast.
https://go.dev/doc/manage-install

Answer (score 0):

It probably you installed the go1.18.2.darwin-amd64.pkg but with **x86-64** package. I got the same issue by installing that.

Actually, we should install go1.18.2.darwin-amd64.pkg with the **ARM64** one.